# Displaying results depending on its date (month & year)

Tags: php

I have load of data in the DB and each row has a date column

Currently im pulling all the results onto a page but i want to split it up into months. 
I have buttons on my page that when clicked should display only the appropriate results, for example when the button January 2012 is click all the results for that month will be displayed

Heres an example of what im trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY7iN.jpg

=================================================================================

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "pass");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename"); 

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='0'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$i++;
if($i%2==0) $class="cell1"; else $class="cell2";
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
echo "<td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]." thinks that it will happen on      
<span class=datecolor>".date('l jS F Y',strtotime($row['date']))."</span></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }  

  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

=========================================================================

Im looking for a little help on how i can display the results for each month by clicking on the buttons without it appearing all at the one time.

Also the when the page is first viewed id like it to automatically show the results for the current month, for example it if viewed now it would display the August results

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question (displaying one month at a time), your best bet is to make your database do all of the work for you. Right now your SQL SELECT statement looks like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

You want to add a `WHERE` clause that will restrict this query to only show you rows for a certain month… something like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '05/01/2011' AND '05/31/2011'
```

You may need to tweak this for your particular database engine or setup. [Here's one WHERE tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-where-sql-tutorial/); you can find tons more on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your buttons be links to the page with a query string that specifies the month (for example: www.mysite.com/mypage?month=september). Then get the month from the query string and only select the rows that are in that month.

See:

[PHP parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

[$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

[MySQL Select a Date Range](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/53025)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$month = isset($_GET['month']) ? intval($_GET['month']) : 0;
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? intval($_GET['year']) : 0;

if( empty($month) ){
    $month = date('n');
}
if( empty($year) ){
    $year = date('Y');
}

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date_field)="'.$month.'" AND YEAR(date_field)='.$year.'"');
// or maybe use BETWEEN syntax

while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) ){
    // do something...
}
```

Year is needed because one month number may belong to diffent year number (03-2010,03-2011 etc..), and, so when your data covers dates from different years, you cannot determine what data you need only having month

Comment: how would i then link the buttons if i was to use this?

Comment: im still a little unsure of how this will sit within my code and how the buttons will link,

Comment: It is your choice. If you prefer to pass year and month to PHP as numbers, you may link using addresses like `mypage.php?month=3&year=2011`. Of course, you must add MySSQL connection initialization to my code and table output inside loop.

Comment: If you do not know how to pass variables to PHP from html page, take a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: ok, is there somewhere i can send u a small snippet of code to look to see if ive done this correctly?

msn or email ???

Comment: ive hit a bit of a brick wall here with adding this code, it doesnt seem to be doing anything... would i be able to show u this somehow?

Comment: Send me your code to my e-mail, it`s address must be in my profile

Comment: no email address on ur profile... can u email me and ill forward it onto you??